# Whatever happened to VISIONary?

Tags: rooting

A number of people on here have recommended I give VISIONary a try out on my HTC Desire HD. But I can't find it anywhere - has it been decommissioned?

Comment: Please don't use device tags like `htc-desire-hd` unless your question is absolutely specific to the device (in this case it's really about the app).  Thanks!

Comment: ok. I wasn't sure if I needed a specific flavour of it to match my handset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't been updated since November, and was removed from the official Market, but as far as I know it's still around.  You can get it from http://android.modaco.com/content/software/320350/19-nov-r14-visionary-one-click-root/

Comment: Thanks much. I have it but I'm not sure its working - it doesnt seem to give me a success message when I try Temprooting.