# Rooted Phone but still can't uninstall Apps

Tags: applications, uninstallation, bloatware

So I finally [temp-rooted](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8033/whatever-happened-to-visionary) my HTC Desire HD and set about trying to uninstall some of the stock apps that came with it (Stocks (no pun intended), Facebook for HTc and so on). But it won't let me - the 'Uninstall' link is disabled inside Settings-> Applications.

Do I need to do a 'full' root to achieve my goal or am I missing something?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I would be *extremely* careful about removing seemingly unneeded system apps.  In most manufacturer overlays (HTC's Sense, Motorola's BLUR, Samsung's TouchWiz, etc.) some of these apps might be very closely integrated with "core" apps such as Contacts or Phone/Dialer, for example.  Removing things you might think are useless (e.g. Happenings.apk on MotoBLUR) can cause instability of the core apps and make them Force Close on launch.  Try to do a search on this site (or better yet appropriate section on XDA-Developers forums) for a list of apps that can be safely removed from your handset.

Comment: TouchWiz is actually fairly loosely integrated, fortunately, but it's always best to make a backup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Settings application doesn't let you uninstall system apps; it's got nothing to do with root.  It doesn't check for root, or anything like that.

I recommend using [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to remove system apps, it works wonderfully.  I even had a regular app yesterday that the Market just couldn't uninstall for some reason, and TB took care of it.

Comment: Cool, many thanks. It looks like Titanium Backup requires root access to work so I'll give it a try with temp-root.