# I've rooted my tablet, now how do I get rid of this bloatware?

Tags: root-access, bloatware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rooted Phone but still can't uninstall Apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8290/rooted-phone-but-still-cant-uninstall-apps)

I just went through the process of rotting my Galaxy Tablet 10.1. I used [these instructions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1239185), and the process went smoothly so I think it was a success.

However, everything looks pretty much the same as before, so I can't really tell if anything has actually happened.

In any case, part of the reason I did this was so that I could remove some pre-installed bloatware off the tablet. My understanding was that if the tablet was rooted, I would have the ability to do this.

If this is the case, though, I can't tell how. There is still no uninstall option in Settings->Applications->Manage Applications for the unwanted apps.

Do I have to do something else?

Is my tablet not actually rooted as I thought?

Was I wrong that a rooted tablet would be able to remove bloatware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can remove bloatware from rooted tablet, but not using stock uninstall utility. Use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to remove those bloatware. Its the simplest way.

The meaning of being rooted means you can access device as root user of Linux (Android is Linux). A root user can do everything on system. Stock settings utilities aren't designed to use this capability. So, you need to use a third-party app. Titanium Backup take over system as root user, so it can do everything including bloatware removal from ROM.