# Disable the default browser in ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can deleting stock web browser cause problems?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22912/can-deleting-stock-web-browser-cause-problems)

Ok since I got chrome now, can I safely disable the stock browser in the apps menu? Are there other services/apps on the phone that require the use of the stock browser?

Answer (score 1):

I installed Chrome and disabled the built-in browser months ago and haven't had a hint of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You should be good to go.  If any app specifically asks for the stock browser it isn't particularly well-written and by and large you'll be prompted by any app that needs a browser but can't identify what you've set as default.

Comment: Even Google+ asked for the default browser. If the app can't handle a link that's the only way to make sure that it won't try to open it again and again and again and...

Comment: Shouldn't an app request whichever browser the user has set to default, though, rather than asking for a specific app in which to launch the link?

Comment: It should but G+ has a good reason for it. The reason it's like this is that you can set all Google+ to open inside the app. But if the link can't be opened than it can't just open it regularly because than the app itself would open it again, so instead it opens the browser. I don't see another way this could have been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you're rooted, go ahead to disable stock browser apk. Other services may require webView to display webpages which has nothing to do with browser.apk file.